# using cat command with variable unix

Tags: unix, cat

```
sh temp1.sh Gold.txt Silver.txt
2
Gold.txt
$2
```

Silver is second to gold.
It is a unique position in a competition.

```
cat: cannot open $2
```

---

```
tstetlx () /appl/edw/apps/scripts/scenario1> vi temp1.sh
i=$#
echo $i
echo $1
echo $`echo $i`
#cat "$`echo $i`"
cat $2
cat "\$$i"
```

The below command is not printing the contents of the second file passed as an argument to the file.

```
cat "\$$i"
```

Answer (score 0):

Not clear to me what you are trying to do.  Consider using `$1` or `$2`.

The reason that line fails is because the parameter for cat is literally $2 - no attempt by the shell to substitute $2 as if it were a variable.

This is one way to handle the problem.  Note that this is a bash solution.

```
i=$#
echo $i
echo $1
echo $`echo $i`
#cat "$`echo $i`"
cat $2
cat "\$$i"
declare -a arr=( "$0" $@ )
echo  ${arr[i]}
cat ${arr[i]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure a file called Silver.txt exists in the same directory as temp1.sh.

As for the variable indirection you are trying to do with `cat "\$$i"`, you want `eval`:

```
eval cat "\$$i"
```

However, `eval` can be dangerous.  Make sure the variable you will be eval'ing is valid, especially if its contents comes from user input.  Run this and see what I mean:

```
eval cat "\$$i;ps -ef"
```

It will run a command if it can be manipulated to contain one.  See this post for a better discussion on why and alternatives: [Why should eval be avoided in Bash, and what should I use instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529220/why-should-eval-be-avoided-in-bash-and-what-should-i-use-instead).